# What is the easiest way to run a local server of a website built using ColdFusion with Coldspring, Reacter, and Model-Glue?

Tags: apache, coldfusion, wampserver, model-glue

Here is the situation: I was given a machine with a subversioned repository of an old website to update/add contents every now and then.  The website is built using ColdFusion and Model-Glue MVC, AND I have no idea (zero) about ColdFusion. The other website we run is on CakePHP and that is good enough learning curve for me. ;(

With that said, I don't have a problem modifying it's contents because its all HTML and javascript. The problem is that with each minor change, I have to commit to the development repository on the server THEN go online to see how the change looks like!
It gets very frustrating just to try different values for a simple thing like the "height" attribute of an html tag!!  And what frustrated me even more is trying to run a local copy on my machine for that repository!

What I tried so far:

- I installed CF10 with WAMP.
- Configured vhosts file for the new server.
- Added my user to ColdFusion Application server service (windows 7x64)

But whenever I try to open it in the browser it gives me "**Exception Service Error Application Exception**"!! Any help please?

**Update: I forgot to ask! how to know the index.cfm file that the website starts with? For example, I know in CakePHP its app/webroot/index.php. What is that in (Coldfusion X Model-Glue)? there are so many index.cfm and application.cfm files!

my httpd-vhosts.conf block about this server is like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName localhost-CF
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/my/webroot/directory/"
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/my/webroot/directory/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
allow from all
order allow,deny
# Enables .htaccess files for this site
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
# Apache will look for these two files, in this order, if no file is specified in the URL
DirectoryIndex index.cfm index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is a link to a Screen Cap --no enough rep ;{ -- of what I get using both servers (not at the same time though) apache and built-in:
[CF10 Local Server Setup Issue](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bwpc8UOGMwadSlpLNDI1aDd3S1k/edit?usp=sharing)

Also, here is a block from **cfusion\logs\application.log**:

```
"Error","ajp-bio-8012-exec-1","08/15/13","10:34:38","PREK","Error during init: Could not find the                 ColdFusion component or interface coldspring.beans.DefaultXmlBeanFactory. Ensure that the name is correct and that the component or interface exists."  
"Error","ajp-bio-8012-exec-1","08/15/13","10:34:38","PREK","Error during exception service init: Element EXCEPTIONSERVICE is undefined in a Java object of type class [Ljava.lang.String;. "  
"Error","ajp-bio-8012-exec-1","08/15/13","10:34:38","PREK","Error during application init: The datasource named cfclientstorage is not a valid client storage DSN. Define client storage DSN through the ColdFusion Administrator."
```

I do have cfclientstorage as a DSN storage and the Administrator tells me its verified!
However, I think, if this exact repository works fine on the server then I should not worry about the code! it most likely a system/server configuration or installation problem (on my local machine).

Comment: coldfusion has a inbuilt webserver running at port 8500 usually (depending on your setup). Did you try running the website at that port than going through Apache?

Comment: Did you run the Web Server Configuration Tool?

Comment: @Sanjeev no i didn't. Does it work if I try it now after I added apache server? I think you mean something like this: localhost:850/.., am I correct? I still need to look how to point coldfusion to the index.cfm file.

Comment: @ScottStroz: Yes, that's how I added the apache server after installation done (with built in server first).

Comment: Can we see your VirtualHost block for the site? Have you verified that Apache is serving HTML files correctly?

Comment: @ScottStroz, I switched to the built-in server again (Thanks to Ryan Anlam http://blog.bittersweetryan.com/2012/02/changing-webroot-of-coldfusion-zeus.html) and it gave me same problem. I'm suspecting maybe I'm not pointing to the real webroot directory?! The reason of my suspision is that I can browse to administrator page but not to my "assumed" webroot directory.

Comment: @trust_words I try not to use the built in web server. I always seem to have pathing issues because on my dev machine, app will live in a subdirectory, whereas in production it is almost always the root of web site.

Comment: The ColdFusion files reside in C:/wamp/www/my/webroot/directory/? Also, can you screen cap the error when you load the page?

Comment: @ScottStroz: if you mean installation files no, they are under C:\ColdFusion10. But if you mean repository files they are under C:\wamp\www\my\webroot\directory\. I posted a link hope it can explain something. (I switched back to apache server now)

Comment: @trust_words Yes. It will still work after you put apache in the front of CF. is your port 8500 ? if yes, then http://localhost:8500/PATH_TO_YOUR_WEBSITE/index.cfm shall work with ease.

if you don't know the port, run "netstat -ano" in command line and compare the PID with the coldfusion.exe PID in the windows task manager.

Comment: just for making things easy, why don't you check the coldfusion Log files present in the cfusion\log\ directory? check the http.log and exception.log. it will record your server error and instantly gives you an idea on what is the 'gremlin' that is failing your installation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using ColdSpring. You need to login into ColdFusion Administrator and add a mapping to your ColdSpring directory for example:

/coldspring --> c:/ColdSpring

Also you will need to set a datasource to point to your "cfclientstorage" database. This is also in ColdFusion Administrator

Comment: Thanks @TechMark2k for reviving the discussion on this issue. I did the second suggestion from before. But I will try the first one and will get back to you about it.